# Несовпадение длины массива при выводе в console.log

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток, уже всю голову сломал. Все коды [здесь](https://github.com/ReinRaus/HashCodeUserJS/tree/475b4e8eaac0dcd17c45bf5194239b5cc82ab517).
Вот такая строка кода

```
console.log(__addons.length, __addons);
```

Выводит:
[image]
Как так?
Кратко смысл: создается массив `__addons`, после этого

```
var scr= document.createElement('script');
scr.innerHTML= "\nwindow.__addons.push(dataToPush);\nconsole.log (addonsLoader.started);";
document.head.appendChild(scr);
```

console.log делается в addonsLoader.init
Внедрение скрипта в developerMode.beforeInit
Функции вызываются в следующем порядке:

```
addonsLoader.initStorage();
developerMode.beforeInit();
addonsLoader.init();
```

Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся. Мой мозг наотрез несогласен с таким выводом в console.log - нужен свежий взгляд.
Для воспроизведения ошибки надо включить режим разработчика. Создать любой новый аддон с экспортируемыми настройками. Например так:

```
{
    name: 'namedsfsdf',
    title: 'title',
    description: 'description',
    settings:{
        test:'5'
    },
    exports:[{name:'test', type:'text', title:'dgd'}],
    run: function() {
    }
}
```

Открыть вкладку настроек для этого аддона и нажать кнопку "Сохранить".
Приглашаю @Yura Ivanov @eicto @strol .

Comment: а что за браузер ? из-за дурацкой идеи personal web вставлять дамп через prompt дамп не влазит в поле :) а в chrome и firebug массивы печатаются как массивы, без свойств.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Вот это](http://jsfiddle.net/5DuBs/2/) повторяет вашу проблему. объясняется просто -  когда console.log выводит массив, он **печатает** строку типа:

```
5 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

а когда вы мышкой её раскрываете, то он обращается к текущему статусу переменной ([ссылки на неё на самом деле](http://jsfiddle.net/5DuBs/5/)). и поэтому выводит текущее значение.

---

исходник примера -- для будущих поколений

```
var a={values:[]};
for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    a.values.push({a: "a"});
}
console.log(a,a.values);
a.values="String интересный эффект";
```

Comment: да, похоже на то. лучше делать тогда 
  
    console.log(a.length,a.toString());

если это чем-то поможет, конечно

Comment: для закрепления материала, выведите массив в console.log(), запретите очищать консоль, обновите страничку и попробуйте раскрыть предыдущий вывод.

Comment: toString() только если его переписать поможет :) ещё так можно:

    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)));

Comment: Спасибо. У меня разрыв шаблона произошёл. Теперь все встало на свои места.

Comment: Вообще нехорошо поступает Хром. Ожидается раскрытие объекта в том виде на который сделан console.log, а не настоящее время.

Comment: @ReinRaus ну а как запомнить состояние ? есть же и циклические объекты...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5DuBs/6/